# Math operators on 2-dimensional arrays in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, for-loop

What I would like to do with the code is to import a `Range.Value` in VBA like a matrix, then to make the ratio of each one of its elements to 100 and finally to put the new matrix in my spreadsheet.

Here's my trial, but "type mismatch" is the error:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim matrix()
    Dim tmp()
    Dim nrow As Integer
    Dim ncol As Integer

    nrow = Range("F2:I142").Rows.Count
    ncol = Range("F2:I142").Columns.Count

    ReDim matrix(nrow, ncol)
    ReDim tmp(nrow, ncol)

    matrix = Range("F2:I142").Value

    For i = 0 To 142
        For j = 0 To 3
            tmp(i, j) = matrix(i, j) / 100
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Is there maybe an error with array indexing?

Comment: EDIT: edited variables declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error because you have used wrong array bounds:

```
ReDim matrix(1 To nrow, 1 To ncol)
ReDim tmp(1 To nrow, 1 To ncol)    

'your code

For i = 1 To 141
    For j = 1 To 4
        tmp(i, j) = matrix(i, j) / 100
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Thank you, maybe replacing `141` and `4` with `nrow` and `ncol` should work as well. Just a question: putting `tmp` in my spreadsheet in, say, `Range("K2:N142")` makes it to create a blank row and a blank column around the matrix. Why does it do so and how can I avoid it?

Comment: matrix array has dimmension (1 to nrow, 1 to ncol), and tmp array has dimmension (0 to nrow, 0 to ncol). So the problem was that you haven't specify values for tmp(0,j) and tmp(i,0). I've updated my answer and the code should work well now